# Keras network can never classify the last class

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, keras-2

I have been working on my project [Deep Learning Language Detection](https://github.com/aliostad/deep-learning-lang-detection) which is a network with these layers to recognise from 16 programming languages:

[image]

And this is the code to produce the network:

```
# Setting up the model
graph_in = Input(shape=(sequence_length, number_of_quantised_characters))
convs = []
for i in range(0, len(filter_sizes)):
    conv = Conv1D(filters=num_filters,
                  kernel_size=filter_sizes[i],
                  padding='valid',
                  activation='relu',
                  strides=1)(graph_in)
    pool = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pooling_sizes[i])(conv)
    flatten = Flatten()(pool)
    convs.append(flatten)

if len(filter_sizes)>1:
    out = Concatenate()(convs)
else:
    out = convs[0]

graph = Model(inputs=graph_in, outputs=out)

# main sequential model
model = Sequential()


model.add(Dropout(dropout_prob[0], input_shape=(sequence_length, number_of_quantised_characters)))
model.add(graph)
model.add(Dense(hidden_dims))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_prob[1]))
model.add(Dense(number_of_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

So my last language class is SQL and in the test phase, it can never predict SQL correctly and it scores 0% on them. I thought this was due to poor quality of SQL samples (and indeed they were poor) so I removed this class and started training on 15 classes. To my surprise, now F# files had 0% detection and F# was the last class after removing SQL (i.e. the one-hot-vector where the last position is 1 and the rest is 0). Now if a network that was trained on 16 used against 15, it would achieve a very high success rate of 98.5%.

The code that I am using is pretty simple and available mainly in [defs.py](https://github.com/aliostad/deep-learning-lang-detection/blob/master/defs.py) and [data_helper.py](https://github.com/aliostad/deep-learning-lang-detection/blob/master/data_helper.py)

Here is the result of network trained with 16 classes tested against 16 classes:

```
Final result: 14827/16016 (0.925761738262)
xml:        995/1001 (0.994005994006)
fsharp:     974/1001 (0.973026973027)
clojure:        993/1001 (0.992007992008)
java:       996/1001 (0.995004995005)
scala:      990/1001 (0.989010989011)
python:     983/1001 (0.982017982018)
sql:        0/1001 (0.0)
js:     991/1001 (0.99000999001)
cpp:        988/1001 (0.987012987013)
css:        987/1001 (0.986013986014)
csharp:     994/1001 (0.993006993007)
go:     989/1001 (0.988011988012)
php:        998/1001 (0.997002997003)
ruby:       995/1001 (0.994005994006)
powershell:     992/1001 (0.991008991009)
bash:       962/1001 (0.961038961039)
```

And this is the result of the same network (trained against 16) ran against 15 classes:

```
Final result: 14827/15015 (0.987479187479)
xml:        995/1001 (0.994005994006)
fsharp:     974/1001 (0.973026973027)
clojure:        993/1001 (0.992007992008)
java:       996/1001 (0.995004995005)
scala:      990/1001 (0.989010989011)
python:     983/1001 (0.982017982018)
js:     991/1001 (0.99000999001)
cpp:        988/1001 (0.987012987013)
css:        987/1001 (0.986013986014)
csharp:     994/1001 (0.993006993007)
go:     989/1001 (0.988011988012)
php:        998/1001 (0.997002997003)
ruby:       995/1001 (0.994005994006)
powershell:     992/1001 (0.991008991009)
bash:       962/1001 (0.961038961039)
```

Has anyone else seen this? How can I get around it?

Comment: Your link is wrong, I fixed it for you. Please check.

Comment: Hard to tell without the network definition. Also your code is very hard to read as it is very un-pythonic and un-numpy-ic...

Comment: @NilsWerner I have put the code where I create the network. That is very easy to read.

Comment: Could you check if your sql files are read properly from folders?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko yes. And as I explained, if I reduce to 15 class, it will be F# which would score 97% in 16 class case.

Comment: just a guess - maybe you have too much dropout?

Comment: @denfromufa why last class always? And scoring 0?

Comment: I find it weird that you have a dropout directly at the inputs. Any specific reason?

Comment: How do you compute `number_of_classes` passed to `model.add(Dense(number_of_classes))`?

Comment: @cantordust code is here https://github.com/aliostad/deep-learning-lang-detection/blob/master/train.py#L13

Comment: @DanielMöller well, can you point to a reference that it is weird? You may add an answer, still a worthy and will be upvoted. The network is similar to a 2014 paper on using Keras for text processing,

Comment: When you add a dropout to the inputs, you're actually discarding parts of your input. There may be reasons to do that, but I can't see them here. (But I'm not really an expert)

Comment: Sorry to ask this off-topic question but did you create this diagram ? If yes, which tool are you usign to do that ? Many thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The problem is that your data are not shuffled before being split into training and validation sets. Therefore, during training, all samples belonging to class "sql" are in the validation set. Your model won't learn to predict the last class if it hasn't been given samples in that class.

---

In `get_input_and_labels()`, the files for class 0 are first loaded, and then class 1, and so on. Since you set `n_max_files = 2000`, it means that

- The first 2000 (or so, depends on how many files you actually have) entries in `Y` will be of class 0 ("go")
- The next 2000 entries will be of class 1 ("csharp")
- ...
- and finally the last 2000 entries will be of the last class ("sql").

Unfortunately, Keras does not shuffle the data before splitting them into training and validation sets. Because `validation_split` is set to 0.1 in your code, about the last 3000 samples (which contains all the "sql" samples) will be in the validation set.

If you set `validation_split` to a higher value (e.g., 0.2), you'll see more classes scoring 0%:

```
Final result: 12426/16016 (0.7758491508491508)
go:             926/1001 (0.9250749250749251)
csharp:         966/1001 (0.965034965034965)
java:           973/1001 (0.972027972027972)
js:             929/1001 (0.9280719280719281)
cpp:            986/1001 (0.985014985014985)
ruby:           942/1001 (0.9410589410589411)
powershell:             981/1001 (0.98001998001998)
bash:           882/1001 (0.8811188811188811)
php:            977/1001 (0.9760239760239761)
css:            988/1001 (0.987012987012987)
xml:            994/1001 (0.993006993006993)
python:         986/1001 (0.985014985014985)
scala:          896/1001 (0.8951048951048951)
clojure:                0/1001 (0.0)
fsharp:         0/1001 (0.0)
sql:            0/1001 (0.0)
```

---

The problem can be solved if you shuffle the data after loading. It seems that you already have lines shuffling the data:

```
# Shuffle data
shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(y)))
x_shuffled = x[shuffle_indices]
y_shuffled = y[shuffle_indices].argmax(axis=1)
```

However, when you fit the model, you passed the original `x` and `y` to `fit()` instead of `x_shuffled` and `y_shuffled`. If you change the line into:

```
model.fit(x_shuffled, y_shuffled, batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=num_epochs, validation_split=val_split, verbose=1)
```

The testing output would become more reasonable:

```
Final result: 15248/16016 (0.952047952047952)
go:             865/1001 (0.8641358641358642)
csharp:         986/1001 (0.985014985014985)
java:           977/1001 (0.9760239760239761)
js:             953/1001 (0.952047952047952)
cpp:            974/1001 (0.973026973026973)
ruby:           985/1001 (0.984015984015984)
powershell:             974/1001 (0.973026973026973)
bash:           942/1001 (0.9410589410589411)
php:            979/1001 (0.978021978021978)
css:            965/1001 (0.964035964035964)
xml:            988/1001 (0.987012987012987)
python:         857/1001 (0.8561438561438561)
scala:          955/1001 (0.954045954045954)
clojure:                985/1001 (0.984015984015984)
fsharp:         950/1001 (0.949050949050949)
sql:            913/1001 (0.9120879120879121)
```

Comment: That is very promising. Thank you! I will make the changes and most possibly accept your answer - I think you are to the point and makes sens.

Comment: Good job! Any insights on [this little puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157526/resnet-100-accuracy-during-training-but-33-prediction-accuracy-with-the-same), possibly? :)