# Much higher val_loss (than train loss) for the testing on training experiment in keras

Tags: keras

I encountered a strange thing in a testing-on-training experiment, where the `val_loss` is completely different than the training `loss`, even though they are evaluated on the exact same data `(X,Y)` with the same `batch_size`

Below is the code that I used to train one batch

```
X, Y = valid_datagen.next()
batch_size = len(X[0])
joint_model.fit( X, Y, 
                 batch_size=batch_size,
                 epochs=1,
                 verbose=1, 
                 validation_data=(X, Y))
```

> Train on 12 samples, validate on 12 samples Epoch 1/1 12/12
>   [==============================] - 38s 3s/step - loss: 0.7510 -
>   q_mask_a_loss: 0.4739 - r_mask_a_loss: 0.6610 - q_mask_b_loss: 0.4718
>   - r_mask_b_loss: 0.3164 - pred_a_loss: 1.8092 - pred_b_loss: 0.2238 - q_mask_a_F1: 0.8179 - r_mask_a_F1: 0.5318 - q_mask_b_F1: 0.8389 -
>   r_mask_b_F1: 0.6134 - pred_a_acc: 0.0833 - pred_b_acc: 1.0000 -
>   val_loss: 7.0257 - val_q_mask_a_loss: 6.9748 - val_r_mask_a_loss:
>   14.9849 - val_q_mask_b_loss: 6.9748 - val_r_mask_b_loss: 14.9234 - val_pred_a_loss: 0.6919 - val_pred_b_loss: 0.6944 - val_q_mask_a_F1:
>   0.0000e+00 - val_r_mask_a_F1: 0.0000e+00 - val_q_mask_b_F1: 0.0000e+00 - val_r_mask_b_F1: 0.0000e+00 - val_pred_a_acc: 1.0000 - val_pred_b_acc: 0.0000e+00

Note:

1. the training `loss` is `0.7510` while the `val_loss` is `7.0257`.
2. I've already made the `batch_size` to be equal the number of
   samples, i.e. training only on one batch.
3. I am using `keras`
   2.2.0 with `tensorflow` backend 1.5.0.
4. using `joint_model.evaluate( X, Y, batch_size=batch_size)` gives the same result as the validation.

With regard to the used `joint_model`, it is nothing but a feed-forward CNN with frozen weights in the first several layers. No `Dropout` layer anywhere.

I've completely no idea what's going on here. Does anyone what are potential reasons or how to debug this? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is there any batch normalization in the model?

Comment: I can look into your model if you could provide somehow.

Comment: @Abhishek Mishra Yes. I do have several `BatchNormalization` layers, but same behaviors are observed no matter I set their weights `trainable=True` or `False`. I am now making a google colab notebook for you. Once it is done, I will update its link here.

Comment: This might be useful: [ResNet: 100% accuracy during training, but 33% prediction accuracy with the same data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157526/resnet-100-accuracy-during-training-but-33-prediction-accuracy-with-the-same)