# CNN unexpected predictions in the presence of BatchNormalization layers

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I’m currently building a CNN to classify 2 different classes, starting from CT images (1024 x 1024 px in grey scale). I know I have small datasets: 100 samples for the training/validation set (50 ‘class 0’ and 50 ‘class 1’) and 27 samples (6 and 21) for the test set. After many simulations, this network configuration seems to be the optimal solution:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1024, 1024, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

Below, you can see the other settings:

```
# compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='SGD', metrics=['accuracy'])

# callbacks
earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(min_delta=0.01, monitor = 'accuracy', patience=40, mode='max', restore_best_weights=True)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau()

# Fitting
seed(100)
set_random_seed(100)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.1, epochs=50, shuffle = True, callbacks=[reduce_lr, earlyStopping])
```

As you can see below, the performance seems to be good; indeed, the loss and the validation loss keep decreasing through epochs while accuracies grow more and more.

```
Epoch 1/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 478ms/step - loss: 0.8159 - accuracy: 0.4889 - val_loss: 0.6816 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 2/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 470ms/step - loss: 0.7045 - accuracy: 0.6000 - val_loss: 0.5591 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 3/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 467ms/step - loss: 0.6565 - accuracy: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.4171 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 4/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 474ms/step - loss: 0.6253 - accuracy: 0.6111 - val_loss: 0.0789 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 5/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 474ms/step - loss: 0.6086 - accuracy: 0.6889 - val_loss: 0.0068 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 6/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 474ms/step - loss: 0.6311 - accuracy: 0.6444 - val_loss: 0.0067 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 7/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 468ms/step - loss: 0.5163 - accuracy: 0.7444 - val_loss: 5.7406e-04 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 8/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 473ms/step - loss: 0.5752 - accuracy: 0.7222 - val_loss: 7.9747e-05 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 9/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 475ms/step - loss: 0.5440 - accuracy: 0.7444 - val_loss: 1.9908e-06 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 10/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 468ms/step - loss: 0.5481 - accuracy: 0.7444 - val_loss: 1.5497e-07 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 11/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 471ms/step - loss: 0.5032 - accuracy: 0.7778 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 12/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 475ms/step - loss: 0.5036 - accuracy: 0.7889 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 13/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 471ms/step - loss: 0.4714 - accuracy: 0.8222 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 14/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 470ms/step - loss: 0.4353 - accuracy: 0.8667 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 15/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 467ms/step - loss: 0.4243 - accuracy: 0.8556 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 16/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 471ms/step - loss: 0.4046 - accuracy: 0.8444 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 17/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 479ms/step - loss: 0.4068 - accuracy: 0.8556 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 18/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 476ms/step - loss: 0.4336 - accuracy: 0.8111 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 19/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 470ms/step - loss: 0.3909 - accuracy: 0.8778 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 20/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 470ms/step - loss: 0.3343 - accuracy: 0.9111 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 21/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 475ms/step - loss: 0.4284 - accuracy: 0.8444 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 22/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 469ms/step - loss: 0.4517 - accuracy: 0.8111 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 23/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 465ms/step - loss: 0.3613 - accuracy: 0.9000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 24/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 474ms/step - loss: 0.3489 - accuracy: 0.9111 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 25/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 474ms/step - loss: 0.3843 - accuracy: 0.8778 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 26/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 471ms/step - loss: 0.3456 - accuracy: 0.8889 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 27/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 474ms/step - loss: 0.3643 - accuracy: 0.8778 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 28/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 474ms/step - loss: 0.3856 - accuracy: 0.8889 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 29/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 471ms/step - loss: 0.3988 - accuracy: 0.8667 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 30/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 475ms/step - loss: 0.3948 - accuracy: 0.8778 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 31/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 470ms/step - loss: 0.4920 - accuracy: 0.7333 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 32/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 472ms/step - loss: 0.3573 - accuracy: 0.8889 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 33/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 465ms/step - loss: 0.4097 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 34/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 469ms/step - loss: 0.3378 - accuracy: 0.9111 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 35/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 472ms/step - loss: 0.3782 - accuracy: 0.8889 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 36/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 475ms/step - loss: 0.3891 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 37/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 470ms/step - loss: 0.3851 - accuracy: 0.8889 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 38/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 472ms/step - loss: 0.3569 - accuracy: 0.9000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 39/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 474ms/step - loss: 0.3795 - accuracy: 0.8889 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 40/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 466ms/step - loss: 0.4399 - accuracy: 0.7667 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 41/50
90/90 [==============================] - 42s 466ms/step - loss: 0.4298 - accuracy: 0.8556 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 42/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 473ms/step - loss: 0.3553 - accuracy: 0.8778 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 43/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 474ms/step - loss: 0.3967 - accuracy: 0.8889 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 44/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 475ms/step - loss: 0.3783 - accuracy: 0.8556 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 45/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 474ms/step - loss: 0.3379 - accuracy: 0.9444 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 46/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 473ms/step - loss: 0.3679 - accuracy: 0.9000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 47/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 475ms/step - loss: 0.3074 - accuracy: 0.9333 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 48/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 475ms/step - loss: 0.3210 - accuracy: 0.9333 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 49/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 476ms/step - loss: 0.4226 - accuracy: 0.8556 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 50/50
90/90 [==============================] - 43s 476ms/step - loss: 0.3811 - accuracy: 0.8889 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
```

However, when I tried to predict classes for both datasets (training/validation set and test set) I got unexpected and surprising results: the CNN predicts only one class.

```
model.predict(X_train)

array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]], dtype=float32)


model.predict(X_test)

array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157526/resnet-100-accuracy-during-training-but-33-prediction-accuracy-with-the-same), I found out that this issue can be generated by the `BatchNormalization()` layers. The solution in this post was to predict samples with these few lines:

```
#Prediction on training set
learning_phase = 1
sample_weights_TR = np.ones(100)
ins_TR = [X_train, y_train, sample_weights_TR, learning_phase]
model.test_function(ins_TR)

[0.39475524, 0.8727273] # Average Accuracy = 0.873


#Prediction on test set
sample_weights_TS = np.ones(27)
ins_TS = [X_test, y_test, sample_weights_TS, learning_phase]
model.test_function(ins_TS)

[0.7853608, 0.79562044]  # Average Accuracy = 0.796
```

However, if I launch `model.test_function(ins_TR)` or `model.test_function(ins_TS)` again and again, the results are always different; accuracies keep going down!

```
model.test_function(ins_TS)
[0.7853608, 0.79562044]

model.test_function(ins_TS)
[0.88033366, 0.75]

 model.test_function(ins_TS)
[0.9703789, 0.7068063]

model.test_function(ins_TS)
[0.86600196, 0.69266057]

model.test_function(ins_TS)
[0.79449946, 0.67755103]

model.test_function(ins_TS)
[0.77942985, 0.6691176]

model.test_function(ins_TS)
[0.83834535, 0.6588629]
```

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Do you have any suggestion to improve the CNN?
2. How can I obtain the right predictions, in presence of BatchNormalization() layers?
3. With the solution proposed here, how can I get the  prediction for each sample (I would assess the CNN sensitivity and specificity)?

Thanks in advance,
Mattia

Comment: You are using dropout more than it is needed. I suggest using dropout after your dense layer with a ratio of 0.2. Also, your first dense layer has a few numbers of neurons. Try using 512 neurons for the first dense layer and 256 for the next layer and then use 128 and last layer one(Binary classifier) your activation for the last layer should be sigmoid. If you take a look at your losses you see one epoch it is increasing and another epoch decreasing. Also, please put samples of your dataset. It is important to know the data very well to design the model.

Comment: It is better to become familiar with the concepts of deep learning. You can watch deep learning.ai courses.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is, as mentioned by @Masoud Erfani, that you want to train a binary classifier (classifier with only 2 possible output : 0 or 1) but you are using the sigmoid activation function and the categorical crossentropy loss function, used for a multi-class classifier.

Change your last layer's activation function to be `sigmoid` and the loss function to be `binary_crossentropy`, that should resolve your problems.

Keep me in touch !

Comment: Thanks @Masoud and @ Thibault for you kind advice. Following your suggestions, I changed the loss function and the last activation function and removed most of the Dropout layer. The performance of the network are obviously improved, but probably I will come across the overfitting (too many parameters and few samples).

Comment: Anyway, my question remains. Even with the modifications you suggested me, I reached accuracy near 1 during training; however, when I perform the prediction on the Training set (model.predict(X_train)) I get the same results as before; namely, the CNN seems to predict only one class (i.e., every predictions are approximately equal to 1). As I said before, I believe that the problem is due to the BatchNormalization layers; indeed, trying to launch the same CNN configuration without BatchNormalization layers, I got worse performance on the training set (~90%) but predictions now are consistent.